# package an electron app which uses json-server with concurrently

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-packager, json-server, concurrently

I have built a react application which uses json-server as a fake api backend. I want to package this app with electron.js as a windows application. I was able to use concurrently in the start script as such:

```
"start": "concurrently \"json-server --watch db.json -p 4444\" \"webpack-dev-server --hot --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4000 --config=./webpack.dev.config.js\""
```

to package my project into a windows application how should I make electron run the json server when the application starts.